# Multi-site setup outside public_html and add on domains

Tags: 6, multi-sites

So I have a Drupal site http://experiment-resources.com running on HostGator dedicated server. It's document root is the default public_html directory.

Now I need to setup a multisite environment outside public_html because I dont want to mess with existing website's functionality.

I already added http://arkivtjenesten.no as an Add-On domain and pointed it to /home/myaccount/arkivtjenesten as its document root. All works fine.

Now I need to add another domain , http://assistertselvhjelp.no . I added this as an add on domain and pointed its doc root to /home/myaccount/arkivtjenesten , same as the previous site. I also added its own settings.php so that it will have its own database. The problem now is if I type in http://assistertselvhjelp.no in the browser it only shows the Apache page.

Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of multi-site: you use one Drupal installation (core) to host several sites. But according to your problem, you want a separate instance of Drupal installation and hence it's considered a "multi-site".

You need edit your virtual host file and point http://assitertselvh.no to the specific folder you're hosting to:

Please use the following guide to edit your virtual host.

http://drupal.org/node/111238

Comment: Yes I want a single Drupal instance (codebase) shared across several sites, each sites having their own databases.